# Differences between natio, populus, vulgus, cultus, and societas?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, synonyms, politics

Is there a distinct differentiation between the words *natio*, *populus*, *vulgus*, *cultus*, and *societas* in classical Latin? I'm encountering conflicting definitions in various dictionaries.

Comment: I can see why one would be interested in the difference between *natio, populus* and *vulgus*, but what do *cultus* and *societas* have to do with these three?

Answer (score -2):

- natio is racial, familial, group, class, kind, vaguely of other peoples, specially when racially or culturally close
- populus is people (political, public) or folk
- vulgus is throng, crowd
- cultus is religion, sect, culture
- societas is society, partnership, fellowship; it took a political/public sense

Comment: Can you add details and cite a source? A quick look at Lewis and Short suggests that there is more to it than what you write.

Comment: "Racial" is a charged and misleading term to use in the context of classical antiquity without a good bit of extra explanation, even if certain dictionaries have been pretty cavalier about it.